# Model creation issues with dictionary and objects

Tags: c#, json

I have a json object that I need to post to a gateway.  It looks as follows.

```
{
  "client_id": "test",
  "non_personalized_ads": false,
  "events": [
    {
      "name": "test",
      "params": {
        "items": [
          {
            "itemitem1": "itemitem1value",
            "itemitem1number": 1
          }
        ],
        "stringparm1": "stringValue1",
        "intparm1": 1
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to create this as a object class in my C# project. The issue is that both the names of these parms are configurable.  So none of these are static property names.

- "itemitem1": "itemitem1value",
- "itemitem1number": 1
- "stringparm1": "stringValue1",
- "intparm1": 1

So in an attempt to achieve that I went with a Dictionary<string, object> as the value can be a number or a string I went with an Object.

```
public class EventParameter
{
    public Dictionary<string, object> Parameters { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, object> Items { get; set; }
    public EventParameter()
    {
        Parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        Items = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }

    public void AddEventParameter(string name, object value)
    {
        Parameters.Add(name, value);
    }
}
```

unfortunately when I do a json pars on this I get. Which is incorrect as my Parameters should be under parms and not under their own object.

```
{
  "client_id": "test",
  "non_personalized_ads": false,
  "events": [
    {
      "name": "hit_event",
      "params": {
        "Parameters": {
          "TestString": "test",
          "testInt": 1
        },
        "Items": {
          "test": 1,
          "test2": 1,
          "test3": "test"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

So how do i get Parameters moved up to parms? It feels like parms needs to be a Dictionary<string, object> but then its going to be missing its items list

```
 "Parameters": {
          "TestString": "test",
          "testInt": 1
        },
```

Im assuming there's something missing in my model design. I have been looking at this too long i cant come up with the solution.   My other idea was could this be done by adding a custom json sterilizer?

Let me know if you want my full model design or the unit test I am using to test with.

## unit test

```
[Fact]
public void Test1()
{

    var postData = new Event() { Name = "EventName" };
    postData.EventParameters.AddEventParameter("TestString", "test");
    postData.EventParameters.AddEventParameter("testInt", 1);
    postData.EventParameters.Items = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        { "test", 1 },
        { "test2", 1 },
        { "test3", "test" },
    };
    
    var data = new EventData()
    {
        ClientId = "test",
        Events = new []
        {
            postData
        }
    };
    
    var options = new JsonSerializerOptions { IgnoreNullValues = true };
    var hold =JsonSerializer.Serialize(data);

    // add breakpoint here
    int i = 1;

}
```

Comment: I have had this issue before and used JObject - build it up dynamically

Comment: Do you actually _use_ that part of the json or do you simply persist to db / read from db? If it is "tranparent" to your code just use JsonObject or even string. That's how we handle config data from frontend that the backend simply "stores and reads" but does not need to really model it in order to function properly.

Comment: I need to be able to create this object as shown here.   This is for backend microservice there is no frontend in this case.  I also really need to model it as this is for a class library.  To go along with the endpoint i am calling.

Comment: @mattsharp could you explain more how to build this up dynamically do you mean when it is preforming the sterilization?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a class that serialises to the first json you showed:

```
class X 
{
    public string client_id {get; set;}
    public bool non_personalized_ads {get; set;}

    public List<EventParameter> events { get;set;}
}

class EventParameter {
    public string name {get; set;}

    
    public Dictionary<string, object> @params {get; set;}
}
```

Test code:

```
var x = new X 
{
    client_id = "test",
    non_personalized_ads = false,
    events = new List<EventParameter>{
        new EventParameter
        {
            name = "test1",
            @params = new Dictionary<string, object>{
                { "items", new Dictionary<string, object> {
                        {"itemitem1", "itemitem1value"},
                        {"itemitem1number", 1}
                    }},
                { "stringparm1", "stringValue1"},
                {"intparm1", 1}
            }
        }
    }
};

var json = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(x, options: new System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions{WriteIndented = true});
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

Comment: OMG your a genius.    why didn't I think of that.  I knew i was missing something.  of course its an object i can just add the list to that.